# JAVA json schema 2 POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

I have to create a REST response. The data is json formatted, and must be structured as the following :

```
{
    "device_id" : { "downlinkData" : "deadbeefcafebabe"}
}
```

"device_id" has to replaced for the DeviceId, for instance:

```
{
    "333ee" : { "downlinkData" : "deadbeefcafebabe"}
}
```

or

```
{
    "9886y" : { "downlinkData" : "deadbeefcafebabe"}
}
```

I used http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/  and this is the result:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"device_id"
})
public class DownlinkCallbackResponse {

    @JsonProperty("device_id")
    private DeviceId deviceId;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("device_id")
    public DeviceId getDeviceId() {
    return deviceId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("device_id")
    public void setDeviceId(DeviceId deviceId) {
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

and

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"downlinkData"
})
public class DeviceId {

    @JsonProperty("downlinkData")
    private String downlinkData;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("downlinkData")
    public String getDownlinkData() {
    return downlinkData;
    }

    @JsonProperty("downlinkData")
    public void setDownlinkData(String downlinkData) {
    this.downlinkData = downlinkData;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

But based on this POJOs I can't set the deviceID:

```
DownlinkCallbackResponse downlinkCallbackResponse = new DownlinkCallbackResponse ();

        DeviceId deviceId = new DeviceId();
        deviceId.setDownlinkData(data);     
        downlinkCallbackResponse.setDeviceId(deviceId);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(downlinkCallbackResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: "I can't set the deviceID" what do you mean by that???

Comment: there is no setter in the POJO to replace device_id for the real ID

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923458/180100 for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get following json string

```
 { "downlinkData" : "deadbeefcafebabe"}
```

create json object  ( Lib : java-json.jar )

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
```

put above json string into json object.

```
 obj.put("333ee", jsonString);
```

that will create following json string

```
{

"333ee" : { "downlinkData" : "deadbeefcafebabe"}
}
```

I hope this will help you. :-)