# spring boot jackson generate dynamic property name with hierarchical levels

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller

How to apply dynamic property name with counter in it.?

I am building a spring boot rest api that returns the following response object.
Response object is a structure with hierarchical levels. Instead of showing all the "levels" property name as default "levels", i want to dynamically put the level number to it as explained in the below sample json.

```
public class Root {
    private String id;
    private List<Level> levels;
    }


public class Level {
    private String name;
    private List<Level> levels;
    }
```

***current json output:***

```
{
  "id" :"testid",
  "levels" : [
         {
          "name" :"test1"
          "levels" : [
              {
                 "name": "test3"
                 "levels" : []
              }
}
```

***Sample expected json:***

```
{
  "id" :"testid",
  "level1" : [
         {
          "name" :"test1"
          "level2" : [
              {
                 "name": "test3"
                 "level3" : []
              }
}
```

Comment: if you want dynamic naming, i would recommend using `Map<String,Object>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923458/11538031

Answer (score 0):

i solved it as follows, by adding a field that contains current level and appending that to the field name.

```
public class Root {
    private String id;

    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Level> levels;

    @JsonIgnore
    private int level;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, List<Level>> any() {
        return Collections.singletonMap("level"+level, levels);
    }

    }


public class Level {
    private String name;

    private List<Level> levels;

    @JsonIgnore
    private int level;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, List<Level>> any() {
        return Collections.singletonMap("level"+level, levels);
    }
    }
```